# How to sync Git commit message, tag message and the CHANGELOG

Tags: git, git-commit, changelog

I want to know the best practices for handling the above. I keep a changelog for my project which I update with detailed information on changes. I also add a summary to the commit message, and add a similar message to the version tag. But what's the difference between, say, a summary on changelog, the commit message, and tag message?

---

CHANGELOG

v1.0.0 - Added this that and that, and changed this.

- change 1
- change 2
- change three or somthing

---

git commit -am "..."

Added this that and that, and changed this.

---

git tag v1.0.0 -m "..."

v1.0.0 - Added this that and that, and changed this.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tag message can represent a summary of the changes, not a specific step like commits do.
The changes happens between two tags.

Actually, if your commmit messages are well written, you could extract from them your changelog: see "[Very Easy Changelogs with Git](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1649/very-easy-changelogs-with-git)"

```
git log 1.0.0...1.1.0 --no-merges --pretty=format:'<li> %s &mdash; %cn &bull; <a href="http://github.com/<username>/<repo>commit/%H" target="_blank">%h</a></li>'
```

That can generate a changelog HTML page similar to http://mun.ee/Changelog.
That way, you don't have to version and maintain a separate `ChangeLog.md` file.

---

Note: starting git 2.0.x/git 2.1 (Q3 2014), the name of the tag will be part of the default prompt message.
See [commit d78f340](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d78f340ed6250dfe8de6e039acc56a013bcf3637) by [(`mirabilos`)](https://github.com/mirabilos):

#### [`builtin/tag.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d78f340ed6250dfe8de6e039acc56a013bcf3637/builtin/tag.c): show tag name to hint in the message editor

> Display the tag name about to be added to the user during interactive editing.

Comment: @MagnusBack thank you for suggesting the `--no-merges` option. I have included it in the answer.